# Hide the qty box on product detail page based on attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I want to hide the qty box on the product details page but only for items with a certain attribute set.  I know i need to edit the addtocart.phtml file with an if statement.  I found a similar issue solved with this if statement which works:

```
        <?php if($_product->getStockItem()->getMaxSaleQty() > 1): ?>
            <div class="qty-wrapper">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

But, I don't want to base it off of MaxSaleQty. I want to base the condition on the qty available.  Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you almost there just need right condition.

You should replace this code from your qty box code.

```
    <?php 
    $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
    $attributeSetModel->load($_product->getAttributeSetId());
    $productAttributeSetName = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
    if($productAttributeSetName != "Your attibute set Name for hide qty"): 
    ?>
    <div class="qty-wrapper">
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Qty')) ?>" class="input-text qty" />
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is all being done inside the addtocart.phtml file.  Pardon my ignorance but does the syntax need to be different?  I can't seem to get this solution to work.  As is, the code text shows up in my page.  When I enclose the above code in <?php code ?> then I loose the qty box AND the Add To Cart button for some reason on ALL products, not just the ones that match my attribute set.

Comment: Can you please post the code so I can correct that.

Comment: I have updated my original question with the complete current code section pulled directly out of my addtocart.phtml file.

Comment: Hii Galen, I updated my answer with your code. Please replace it with your code . You can tell me if anything goes wrong.

Comment: This works perfectly and is now an easy way to hide the qty box based on the Attribute Set of the product.  Thank you to jaydip sinh Parmar.

Comment: It's really good to hear.can you please accept an answer by clicking right - sigh on the left side of an answer. so It will help others.